# Access denied errors on a COM+ application

Tags: components

This is an old school issue.  We've got some COM+ applications written in VB6.  Currently they run on our production Windows 2003 Server, but I want to test some items and so I've made the necessary changes and put it onto a test Windows 2003 Server.  I can run the application fine, but when our users attempt to run against it they get a, "Permission denied" access error.  I've tested it and it appears to me to be related to status within Active Directory.  I'm in the domain administrators group, and our users are not.

I've not really done much with COM+ apps in a while, so I don't remember how to fix this.  Where do I look to solve this problem?  What do I have to do, so that our users can run the COM+ apps against the test server?

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered what the problem is.  The error being raised (#70, "Permission denied") was due to the fact that the user wasn't in the correct group on the server.  What I had to do was enter the group the user is in, to the **Distributed COM Users** group the server.  Once I did that, then the user was able to run the COM+ component fine.